# Saml 2.0 Identity Provider with Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, saml-2.0

I'am trying to implement an saml 2.0 identity provider with symfony, but can't decide which bundle to use, lightsaml seems to be used for Service providers, others like samplesamlphp or oneloginsaml are either with native php or symfony 2, can you please recommend a tutorial or a bundle i can use to implement this identity provider

I tried this [tutorial](https://imbringingsyntaxback.com/implementing-a-saml-idp-with-laravel/) but can't see it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the process of implementing an SAML 2.0 identity provider with Symfony 4 as well.

I have chosen to use the LightSaml IdP even though it lacks proper documentation. I plan to draft some documentation myself once the project is done.

At the moment, I have ported [LightSaml IdP sample code](https://github.com/lightSAML/lightSAML-IDP/tree/master/web/idp) inside controller actions and proper authentication is done by implementing an AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator class from the Guard feature in Symfony Security component.

I am still scratching my head on how to properly use an incoming SAML authentication request to redirect the user back to the SP once he is authenticated locally on the IdP.

Right now I have chosen to validate the entity ID the user is coming from then initiating a new authentication from the IdP back to the SP. Not the cleanest way, but it works for my usage.

Comment: Thanks you @chMat for your answer, i actually opted for lightSaml Idp too, and it worked for me

Comment: @ChMat I am using this package with Okta login, but I am getting `uid` missing error after successful login in Okta. Can you please help me or guide me